# Recursively delete folders and files and exclude a specific subfolder

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have the following folder structure:

```
2013/01/
2013/02/  
2013/03/ 
...
```

I want to delete every folder and file in there except for the following structure:

```
2013/0x/image/web/mailing
```

How can I do this with a CMD command on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

```
robocopy source destination /XD dir_to_exclude
```

http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html