# Prevent cmd.exe from deleting files in hidden subfolder

Tags: cmd.exe

I have the following file structure

```
Parent\Deploy                 (folder)
Parent\Deploy\.svn            (hidden folder)
Parent\Deploy\.svn\file1      (regular file)
Parent\Deploy\.svn\file2      (regular file)
Parent\Deploy\.svn\file3      (regular file)
Parent\Deploy\file4           (regular file)
Parent\Deploy\file5           (regular file)
Parent\Deploy\file6           (regular file)
Parent\Deploy\Something       (regular folder)
Parent\Deploy\Something\file7 (regular file)
```

Lets say I'm at C:\Parent at the moment and I would like to delete all the files 4,5,6,7 using the DEL command.

Here is my attempt:

```
1) DEL /f /q /s .\Deploy 
2) DEL /f /q /s /A:-H .\Deploy
```

But this deletes the files in the hidden .svn too. The second one only excludes files that are hidden, but file 1-3 are "normal", so it deletes them anyway..

Comment: Please see related: https://superuser.com/questions/661768/recursively-delete-folders-and-files-and-exclude-a-specific-subfolder?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I recursively delete all files except those in hidden directories?

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
rem walk file tree, 1/ finding non-hidden directories then 2/ finding files.
rem 1/ find non-hidden directories
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`dir /b /s /a:d-h`) do (
  rem 2/ find and delete files
  echo Processing directory: %%i
  for /f "usebackq  tokens=*" %%j in (`dir /b /a:-d %%i 2^> nul`) do (
    echo Processing file: %%i\%%j
    del /f /q "%%i\%%j"
    )
  )
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [del](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html) - Delete one or more files.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) - Redirection operators.

Comment: thanks, this is complicated, really just expected someone to say     del /magic

Comment: @user230910 Unfortunately `del` does not have a `/magic` option ;)